# Need help translating MATLAB code to C

Tags: c, matlab

I have trouble translating the following code into C, as the format for array indexing in C slightly differs from MATLAB. If I could get some pointers (get it?) as how to translate the following code, I'd greatly appreciate it. I am only stuck at the following lines, as the indexing in C won't allow me to do it as follows:-

```
b = a(x:x+1, y:y+1);
a(x:x+1, y:y+1) = b;
```

My code:-

```
a = [1 2 3 4; 2 3 4 5; 3 4 5 6; 4 5 6 7];
c = dctmtx(2);
q_mtx = [16 11; 12 12];

for x = 1:2:M
    for y = 1:2:N


        b = a(x:x+1, y:y+1); %<----HOW DO I DO THIS IN C???

        b = c*b*c';


        b = b./q_mtx ;


        a(x:x+1, y:y+1) = b; 
    end
end
```

Your help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: How are you storing arrays in C? Using vector class, or 2D arrays (pointer to pointers), or as 1D array (with row or column major order)?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking about as I am a beginner at C, but I normally declare my arrays as such int a[4][4]; .. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no build-in operators for subscripting the arrays.
So, you can either look up for suitable libraries (I think, for 2D arrays some Image processing libraries can work, like `OpenCV`), or write your one code.

The line you are interested in is easy to translate into C.

If in Matlab you have `b = a(x:x+1, y:y+1);`, in `C` it would be four lines:

```
b[0][0]=a[x][y];
b[1][0]=a[x+1][y];
b[0][1]=a[x][y+1];
b[1][1]=a[x+1][y+1];
```

Here I assume that you defined arrays statically (as you wrote in comments). 
This is an advantage of the Matlab - it is really convenient to work with matrices.

Edit: regarding your question in comments, for bigger size you can use for loops:

Matlab code `b = a(x:x+32, y:y+55)` would correspond to

```
for(int i=0;i<32;i++)
     for(int j=0;j<55;j++)
         b[i][j]=a[x+i][y+j];
```

Comment: Thanks @mikhail !
I really appreciate it! :)
Is there a way I can do it with loops though?

Comment: No problem! What exactly do you want to do with loops?

Comment: For example, if the matrix was bigger than 4*4, say, 32*32.. Writing manually the code below for 32 times does sound a bit tedious.. Is there a way to do it with loops?
`b[0][0]=a[x][y];`
`b[1][0]=a[x+1][y];`
`b[0][1]=a[x][y+1];`
`b[1][1]=a[x+1][y+1]; `